# c# Button Press Detection

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a "web browser" in C#, and I'm coming across problems. I don't think my button to go to the navigated URL is working, and I don't know how to test it. When you click the button, it runs `mainBrowser.Navigate(urlTextBox.Text);`, but that's not working for some reason. This is my code:

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox browserGroup; //container of sorts
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox urlTextBox; //self-explanatory
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button navigateToURL; //button to go
        private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser mainBrowser; //browser
        private void navigateToURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //on the button's click
        {
            mainBrowser.Navigate(urlTextBox.Text);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I literally just started c# today.

Comment: How exactly do you know your click handler is being invoked? Perhaps it isn't. Is your WebBrowser control actually visible in your UI with a size larger than zero pixels? Is it not occluded by other controls "sitting" over the WebBrowser control? There are so many possibilities how a program can behave differently as you expect. Without knowing the code and the UI setup it's not possible to say anything with confidence regarding your problem...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I assumed that the button_click function would invoke it.

Comment: Programmer mistake #1: Shooting oneself in both feet, the knee caps and the buttocks by just assuming things. Don't assume (i know, it's easier said than done). Verify and double-check. Programming is an activity that does not go well together with a "belief-based" approach ;-)

Comment: Not working how? Goes to the wrong page, gives you an error, does something else? How are you setting references to mainBrowser or urlTextBox? How are you invoking the method?

Comment: @Chuck Simply nothing is happening. When I was debugging, I made it to console.writeline the value of the textbox.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Touché.

Comment: The WebBrowser control is ancient and uses Internet Explorer, which is deprecated. You can use a third-party library called CefSharp, which allows you to embed Chrome into your WinForms apps for a more modern experience.

Comment: @FelixAn yeah i was gonna change that in a later version, but thanks for telling me the library because I had no idea that existed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Visual Studio IDE ...

So, here are some directions for you to start debugging and solve it yourself:

1. Place a breakpoint inside the 'navigateToURL_Click' event handler method. Run on debug mode, add a URL to the URL text box and check if you can catch the 'navigateToURL' button click there.
2. If that doesn't work, check the button 'Click' event in the button properties dialog. It should point to your 'navigateToURL_Click' method, as seen in this next image:

   [image: Visual Studio properties dialog showing the Click event]
3. On the other end, if that breakpoint works, you can debug and watch the 'urlTextBox.Text' value to see if it is correct.

That's the idea of debugging (an inseparable part of any coding), from here you can think of more checks & test ideas like this ...

Good luck with C#... Have fun coding ...